# Git subtree add does not show per-file history on added files... correct behaviour?

Tags: git, tortoisegit, git-subtree

I've never used `git subtree` before, but am trying to migrate a git repository into my code repo as below:

```
C:\code>git subtree add -P database/scripts c:\git\other-repo HEAD -m="Migrate from other-repo"
```

I get no errors and I can see all the commits merging into my history, and I *can* see the diffs on merged historical commits *but* when I try to look at the log of an individual file that was merged in (in TortoiseGit) it only shows a single commit, rather than dozens in `other-repo`. The commit history of the file isn't shown even though I can see the commits and diffs *are* present in the repository history

I can't screenshot the commits but since I'm not using `--squash` I'm wondering if this is expected. Am I misunderstanding how subtree works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During that merge commit, files also get "renamed" : a file that was located at `that/file.sql` in the original repo is now located at `database/scripts/that/file.sql`.

Try running :

```
git log --graph -- database/scripts/that/file.sql that/file.sql
```

you should see commits that touch to both locations.

---

`git log` also has a way to not handle merge commits by default ; the following combination of options seem to work on my machine :

```
# '--cc' is one of the options that tell git log to inspect the content of merge commits
git log --cc --follow --graph -- database/scripts/that/file.sql
```

Comment: Ah, I think Tortoise has a "track renames/moves" option somewhere so that might show results too, I'll check... sounds like everything is as it should be though.

Comment: @Mr.Boy : yes ; if "track renames" isn't enough, do check if you see an option that relates to [`--diff-merges`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---diff-mergesoffnoneonfirst-parent1separatemcombinedcdense-combinedcc), stating "combined" or "condensed combined"